# "Task at hand" or "Task in hand"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Should "at" or "in" be used in the following sentence?

> Attention is more like a gas tank that refills during short breaks from the task **at hand**, according to Lleras' study.

Comment: I was shocked to see that "task in hand" gets a reasonable number of hits on Google. I've only ever heard "task at hand".

Comment: Not only that, dictionaries also list "task in hand": https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in-hand

Comment: And OALD's definition of "in hand": the job, question, etc. in hand is the one that you are dealing with https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hand_1#hand_idmg_21

Comment: "at hand" means "needing to be dealt with." So a task at hand is one that has not been dealt with.

Answer (score 2):

The "task at hand" is an idiom that means "the work someone is doing" (according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20task%20at%20hand) AmE).  That definition fits for the example you provided.  Searching "[task in hand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20task%20in%20hand)" on Merriam Webster (AmE) will not result in an answer.

According to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matter-in-hand) in regard to the "matter at hand", a similar idiom, "at hand" is AmE and "in hand" is BrE, which is why MW may not have a definition for the latter.

As you have additionally noted below, Longman has the definition of "[at hand](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/at-hand)" as "needing to be dealt with now". "[In hand](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in-hand)," is defined as "being done or dealt with."

Comment: Of course "task in hand" exists. "Our officers have to concentrate 100 per cent on the task in hand." https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in-hand

Comment: I have literally never heard this; I do also think this example should be "task at hand".

Comment: Do you equally reject "job in hand"? https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hand_1#hand_idmg_21

Comment: Actually, yes...  I may be incorrect, of course.  To me, as a native speaker, both sound equally wrong.

Comment: In your example, *task at hand* is correct meaning *something that is to be done*. A search shows that *task n hand*  can be used in the same sense. But I think there is another sense of *task in hand*: *No worries. I have the task in hand.*  means that I'm managing it competently.

Comment: What about "matter in hand"?

Comment: There it is!  It all makes sense now.  According to Cambridge, "in hand" is BrE and "at hand" is AmE.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matter-in-hand

Comment: Longman has this definition of "at hand": needing to be dealt with now. For "in hand," it says, "if something is in hand, it is being done or dealt with."

Comment: It seems you are more than capable of answering your own question! :)  Perhaps what you said is true.  I have never heard of the Longman dictionary, however, so I cannot say much regarding its verity.  Both descriptions (needing to be done/being done) seem to be quite interchangeable in practice, at least.  This being your question, of course, feel free to use whichever you choose!

Comment: Longman's definition leaves open the possibility that something that needs to be dealt with (at hand) is not necessarily being dealt with (in hand).

Comment: At least in AmE, saying that something is the “task at hand” does not mean that it is not being dealt with. Example: “I’ll do X later. The task at hand (which I’m doing right now) is Y.”